# How to customized packing slip for Transfer Order in NetSuite using Advanced PDF?

Tags: pdf, netsuite, transfer, fulfillment

I've customized packing slip in NetSuite using advanced pdf. It is working fine for Item Fulfillments created from Sales Order but the itemline is empty when the item fulfillment is from Transfer Order. Anyway to fixed this?Thank you in advanced!

```
<#if record.item?has_content>

<table class="itemtable" style="width: 100%; font-size: 8pt;" margin-
bottom="1px">
<thead>
<tr style="border-bottom: 2px solid #889588; background-color: #e3e3e3; 
border-top: 2px solid #889588;">
<th colspan="12">Description</th>
<th colspan="3">SKU</th>
<th align="right" colspan="4">Quantity</th>
<th align="right" colspan="4">Memo</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<#if record.showAddlItemsPackSlip == 'NONE'><!-- start items --><#list 
record.item as item><#list salesorder.item as tranline><#if 
tranline.line==item.orderline><tr style="border-bottom: 1px solid #889588">
<td colspan="12">${item.description}</td>
<td colspan="3">${item.item}</td>
<td align="right" colspan="4">${item.quantity}</td>
<td align="right" colspan="4">${item.custcol_description}</td>
</tr>
</#if></#list></#list><!-- end items --><#elseif 
record.showAddlItemsPackSlip == 'ALL'><!-- start items from sales order -->
<#list salesorder.item as tranline><#assign shipped=0><#list record.item as 
item><#if tranline.line==item.orderline><#assign shipped=item.quantity>
</#if></#list>
<tr>
<td colspan="12"><span class="itemname">${tranline.item}</span><br 
/>${tranline.description}</td>
<td colspan="3">${tranline.options}</td>
<td align="right" colspan="4">${tranline.quantity}</td>
<td align="right" colspan="4">${tranline.quantitybackordered}</td>
<td align="right" colspan="4">${shipped}</td>
</tr>
</#list><!-- end sales order items --><#elseif record.showAddlItemsPackSlip 
== 'UNFULFILLED'><!-- start items from sales order --><#list salesorder.item 
as tranline><#assign shipped=0><#assign isInList=false><#list record.item as 
item><#if tranline.line==item.orderline><#assign shipped=item.quantity>
<#assign isInList=true></#if></#list><#if isInList || 
tranline.quantitybackordered != 0>
<tr>
<td colspan="12"><span class="itemname">${tranline.item}</span><br 
/>${tranline.description}</td>
<td colspan="3">${tranline.options}</td>
<td align="right" colspan="4">${tranline.quantity}</td>
<td align="right" colspan="4">${tranline.quantitybackordered}</td>
<td align="right" colspan="4">${shipped}</td>
</tr>
</#if></#list><!-- end sales order items --></#if></table>
</#if>
```

Answer (score 0):

We don't have locations and transfer orders so I can't test this, but I'm guessing it could be due to this line in your template:

```
<#list salesorder.item as tranline>
```

This is looking for items on a `salesorder` record.  Try changing it (in each place it occurs) to

```
<#list transferorder.item as tranline>
```

in order to pull data from the `transferorder` and see if it pulls in the correct information.  I'm assuming you have already set the correct templates in the transaction forms etc already.

Comment: Hello!I've tried changing this before but I still get the same result.